# Problema con Type error object take no parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente script:

```
from record import record


class cliente(record):
  nombre = ""
  codigo = 0
  ultimapelicula= None
  habilitado = True
class pelicula (record):
  nombre=""
  codigo = 0
  ultimocliente = 0
  habilitada = True

def abrirbasedatos():
  listaclientes = []
  listapeliculas = []

  ficheroclientes = abrirfichero ("Clientes.txt")
  if ficheroclientes != None:
    poblarlista(listaclientes, ficheroclientes,1)
    ficheroclientes.close()

  ficheropeliculas = abrirfichero ("C:\\Users\\IndyCarpl\\Desktop\\Menuppal\\pythong\\Peliculas.txt")
  if ficheropeliculas != None:
    poblarlista(listapeliculas, ficheropeliculas,2)
    ficheropeliculas.close()
  return listaclientes, listapeliculas

def abrirfichero (nombrearchivo):
  try:
    return open (nombrearchivo, "r")
  except:
    print ("\n\n No se puedo abrir el fichero", nombrearchivo)
    return

def poblarlista(lista, fichero, numerolista):
    for linea in fichero:
        registro = linea.rstrip().split(",")
        if numerolista == 1:
            lista.append(cliente(nombre=registro[0], codigo = int(registro [1]), ultimapelicula = int(registro[2]), habilitado = convertirVF(registro[3])))
        elif numerolista == 2:
            lista.append(pelicula(nombre=registro [0], codigo = int(registro [1]), ultimocliente = int (registro [2]), habilitada = convertirVF(registro [3])))
    return
def convertirVF (cadena):
  if cadena == "True":
    return True
  elif cadena == "False":
    return False

listaclientes, listapeliculas = abrirbasedatos()

print(listaclientes,listapeliculas)
```

---

Al ejecutarlo obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "club.py", line 49, in <module>
    listaclientes, listapeliculas = abrirbasedatos()
  File "club.py", line 19, in abrirbasedatos
    poblarlista(listaclientes, ficheroclientes,1)
  File "club.py", line 39, in poblarlista
    lista.append(cliente(nombre=registro[0], codigo = int(registro [1]), ultimapelicula = int(registro[2]), habilitado = convertirVF(registro[3])))
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

**Edición:**

Agrego mi script `record.py`:

```
import warnings

class metaMetaBunch(type): 

  def __new__(cls, classname, bases, classdict):

    def __init__(self, **kw):

      for k in self.__dflts__: setattr(self, k, self.__dflts__[k])
      for k in kw: setattr(self, k, kw[k])

    def __repr__(self): 

      rep = [ '%s=%r' % (k, getattr(self, k)) for k in self.__dflts__
              if getattr(self, k) != self.__dflts__[k]]
      return '%s(%s)' % (classname, ', '.join(rep))

      # Build the newdict that we'll use as class-dict for the new class
    newdict = {'__slots__':[], '__dflts__':{}, '__init__':__init__, '__repr__':__repr__}

    for k in classdict:
      if k.startswith('__'):
        # Special methods: copy to \emph{newdict}, warn about conflicts.
        if k in newdict:
          warnings.warn("Can't set attr %r in bunch-class %r" % (k, classname))
        else:
          newdict[k] = classdict[k]
      else:
        # Class variables, store name in \texttt{__}\emph{slots}\texttt{__} and name and value as an item in \texttt{__}\emph{dflts}\texttt{__}.
        newdict['__slots__'].append(k)
        newdict['__dflts__'][k] = classdict[k]
    # Finally delegate the rest of the work to \emph{type}.\texttt{__}\emph{new}\texttt{__}
    return type.__new__(cls, classname, bases, newdict)

class record(object):
  # For convenience: inheriting from \emph{record} can be used to get the new metaclass (same as 
  # defining \texttt{__}\emph{metaclass}\texttt{__} yourself).
  __metaclass__ = metaMetaBunch


if __name__ == "__main__":
    class Point(record):
        x = 0.0
        y = 0.0
        color = 'gray'
        q = Point()
        print (q) 

        p = Point(x=1.2, y=3.4)
        print (p)

        r = Point(x=2.0, color='blue')
        print (r)
        print (r.x, r.y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se encuentra en tu clase `record`. Es correcta pero es sintaxis propia de Python 2.x, incompatible con Python 3.x.

---

Para definir asignar una metaclase a una clase en **Python 2.x** se sigue la siguiente sintaxis:

```
class Form(BaseForm):
    __metaclass__ = FormType
    pass
```

En **Python 3.x** se debe hacer:

```
class Form(BaseForm, metaclass=FormType):
    pass
```

---

Es decir, tu clase `record` en `record.py` debe ser:

```
class record(object,  metaclass= metaMetaBunch):
    pass
```

El resto del código es correcto. Te aconsejo identar siempre usando 4 espacios de acuerdo a PEP-8.

Tu `record.py` debe ser así:

```
import warnings

class metaMetaBunch(type):
    def __new__(cls, classname, bases, classdict):

        def __init__(self, **kw):
            for k in self.__dflts__: setattr(self, k, self.__dflts__[k])
            for k in kw: setattr(self, k, kw[k])

        def __repr__(self):
            rep = [ '%s=%r' % (k, getattr(self, k)) for k in self.__dflts__
                    if getattr(self, k) != self.__dflts__[k]
                  ]
            return '%s(%s)' % (classname, ', '.join(rep))

        newdict = { '__slots__':[], '__dflts__':{},
                    '__init__':__init__, '__repr__':__repr__, }

        for k in classdict:
            if k.startswith('__'):
                if k in newdict:
                    warnings.warn("Can't set attr %r in bunch-class %r" % (
                        k, classname))
                else:
                    newdict[k] = classdict[k]
            else:
                newdict['__slots__'].append(k)
                newdict['__dflts__'][k] = classdict[k]

        return type.__new__(cls, classname, bases, newdict)


class record(object,  metaclass= metaMetaBunch):
    pass
```

Para ver esta y otras diferencias entre Python 2 y Python 3 puedes mirarte:

[What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html)

Comment: Hola, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, ese ejercicio lo copie de un curso que hago online, al que hace el video le corre sin ningún problema. Gracias por tu apoyo. Saludos desde Venezuela. voy a implementar tu ayuda.

Comment: @MarcoSalazar si eso es así tus clases `cliente` y `película` son correctas,  el inicializador posiblemente esté en la clase padre `record` en el caso de quién hace el vídeo, pero tu no lo tienes implementado.  Implementa el método `__init__` en tu clase `record`, de lo contrario no te va a funcionar ya que los atributos no serán pasados al padre y sus métodos no los van a poder usar. Si pudieras agregar como tienes la clase `record` podría ayudarte con más precisión como te comenté en la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: el record esta como en el código. solo esto: from record import record. ahora puse lo que me enviaste y me sale esto: [<__main__.cliente object at 0x000000000215F0B8>, <__main__.cliente object at 0x0000000002153FD0>] [<__main__.pelicula object at 0x000000000215F240>, <__main__.pelicula object at 0x000000000215F198>]

***Repl Closed***     no se si cabe mencionar que estoy usando sublime text 3

Comment: @MarcoSalazar entonces debes tener tu clase `record` en un fichero llamado `record.py`, esa es la que necesito ver.

Comment: ok. gracias por la observación, es que estoy nuevo en esto.

Comment: y como hago para enviártela? como un adjunto? a que correo?

Comment: No, simplemente copia el código de la clase en tu pregunta. Para ello editala usando el botón [`editar`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/102863/edit) de debajo de ella. Lo copias, lo pegas en el editor, lo seleccionas (solo el código que acabas de pegar) y puslas `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor para que se idente y formatee como código.

Comment: creo que ya lo hice, cabe destacar que ese record en un principio me dio error de identacion en la 43. por lo que le di una tabulación y ya dejo de darme error pero no  se si quedo bien

Comment: @MarcoSalazar he editado la pregunta. El problema es que en el curso se usa Python 2 y tu usas Python 3. Puedes encontrarte más incompatibilidades pero te aconsejo que sigas con Python 3, Python 2 no va a recibir actualizaciones importantes (2.7 será el último) y dejará de tener soporte en 2020. Recuerda aceptar una respuesta si esta soluciona tu problema, mírate[¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) para saber cómo. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciona al pelo. Creo que ya le di aceptación de respuesta.